# GWT- History Management for web application

Tags: gwt, browser-history, session-management

I am working on History management for my application. I have two views, one is login and the other is main application. I have added local links #login and #application. Now ideally what should happen is, when the user opens the application he should see the login view which has #login token. It works fine. Then when his credentials are validated he goes to application view with token #application. And when he logs out he goes back to #login. All this works fine. But what bothers me is when I change the link token from #login to #application manually, the main application opens directly even after I have logged out. But when I try the same thing in a new tab, it works fine.
The application is vulnerable to attacks which needs to be fixed.
I need some help here.

```
    //When application loads
    History.newItem("application",true);           
    //When login screen loads //     
    History.newItem("login",true); 

    //On change
    History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>(){   

        @Override     
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) { 
            String historyToken   = event.getValue(); 
            if (historyToken.substring(0, 5).equals("login")) {
                login();   
            }
            if (historyToken.substring(0, 11).equals("application")) {
                     mainApplicationView();    
            }
     });
```

When I logout, login() method is called which loads relevant panels into RootPanel and also has #login token inside. Also, the main application panels are removed from rootpanel.

Comment: History.newItem("application",true); //When application loads
History.newItem("login",true); //When login screen loads
//
History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
         String historyToken = event.getValue();
           
         try {
            if (historyToken.substring(0, 5).equals("login")) {
                 RootPanel.get("timeList").remove(mainPanel);
             login();
            }
These are the relevant piece of codes.

Comment: When I logout, I call login() which has relevant panels added and removed from it. login() also contains the #login token.

Comment: I found the mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was inside second if condition:

```
    History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>(){   

            @Override     
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) { 
                String historyToken   = event.getValue(); 
                if (historyToken.substring(0, 5).equals("login")) {
                    login();   
                }
                if (historyToken.substring(0, 11).equals("application")) {
                    startApplication(); //it will again check if the session is valid. If not, login screen will show up. Else mainApplication.
                }
    });
```

After I logout, it should not allow me to see the application page in any case. So, I should make sure that sessionID is valid. I did it only once when the application start but not under History.addChangeHandler. This was a blunder.

```
    String sessionID = Cookies.getCookie("JSESSIONID");
    if(sessionID == null) {
        login();
    } else {
        checkWithServer();
    }
```